# Environment variables when switching users in a bash script

Tags: bash

I have a bash script and need to execute commands as a different user within the script. But when I switch users, I noticed that the environment variables aren't being reset.  For example, if I run the script as user1 and switch to user2, the $HOME environment variable still refers to user1. What's missing?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

whoami  # Prints "user1"
sudo -i -u user2 << EOF
    whoami  # Prints "user2"
    echo ${LOGNAME}  # Prints "user1", NOT "user2"
    echo ${HOME}  # Prints "/home/user1", NOT "/home/user2" as expected
EOF
whoami  # Prints "user1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables are being expanded by your current shell. Not by the `sudo` shell. The sudo shell doesn't see variables it sees literal text.

You need to prevent that. Either by quoting some or all of the heredoc start marker or by escaping the `$` in the heredoc contents.